# permissions of symlinks inside /tmp

Tags: permissions, symlink, tmp, permission-denied

I have 2 users in my machine: `linuxlite` and `otheruser`.

`otheruser` has a file:

```
otheruser@linuxlite:~$ ls -l a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 otheruser otheruser 6 Mar 31 12:47 a
otheruser@linuxlite:~$ cat a
hello
```

`linuxlite` made a file and a symlink in `/tmp`:

```
otheruser@linuxlite:~$ ls -l /tmp/file /tmp/link
-rw-rw-r-- 1 linuxlite linuxlite  3 Mar 31 12:49 /tmp/file
lrwxrwxrwx 1 linuxlite linuxlite 17 Mar 31 12:49 /tmp/link -> /home/otheruser/a
```

Now, although `otheruser` can read `/tmp/file` and `/home/otheruser/a`, he cannot read `/tmp/link`:

```
otheruser@linuxlite:~$ cat /tmp/file
hi
otheruser@linuxlite:~$ cat /home/otheruser/a
hello
otheruser@linuxlite:~$ cat /tmp/link
cat: /tmp/link: Permission denied
```

My question is, **why cannot `otheruser` read a symlink owned by `linuxlite` if he can read the target and also another file owned by him in the same directory as the symlink?**

If it matters, then the permissions on `/tmp` are:

```
otheruser@linuxlite:~$ ls -l -d /tmp
drwxrwxrwt 9 root root 4096 Mar 31 13:17 /tmp
```

Distribution is Linux Lite 3.0, kernel is: Linux 4.4.0-21.generic (i686)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Linux Lite is based on Ubuntu, which [restricts symlinks in world-writable sticky directories](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Features#Symlink_restrictions) (including `/tmp`): symlinks there can only be dereferenced by their owner.

If you create the symlink elsewhere (in `/home/linuxlite` for example) you’ll be able to dereference it in the way you expect.

(Ubuntu isn’t the only distribution to behave in this way; I mentioned the connection between Linux Lite and Ubuntu because the documentation for this is seemingly Ubuntu-specific.)